# Parallel Processing Wikipedia's XML Data Dump with Storm

Tags: java, xml, bigdata, apache-storm

I'm trying to process the wikipedia dump found [here](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/). Specifically with the file - enwiki-latest-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2. This is about 46GB uncompressed. I am currently using the STAX parser in Java (xerces) and am able to extract 15K page elements per second. However the bottleneck seems to be the parser and I have toyed around with aalto-xml but it hasn't helped.

Since I'm parsing each page element in the Storm spout, it is a bottleneck. However, I thought I could simply emit the text between ... tags and have several bolts process each of those page elements in parallel. This would reduce the amount of work the Storm spout has to perform. However I am not sure of the specific approach to take here. If I use a parser to extract the content between tags then that would mean it would parse every single element from the beginning of the  tag until the end. Is there a way to eliminate this overhead in a standard SAX/STAX parser?

Comment: I don't know how it could.  In order to know that the tag in which you want raw XML has closed, I would think that it would need to parse all the XML content inside.  Otherwise an end tag it comes upon may be ambiguous with the one you actually want, and another that is in affect due to a namespace that was introduced, e.g.  It seems like to accomplish this would require generally unsafe assumptions, that maybe can only be applied in specific situations.

Comment: `Xerces` is NOT a Stax parser; maybe you are thinking of SAX? As to using Aalto; since it is at least 2x as fast as Xerces, if you do not observe change you may either be using it incorrectly (like not reusing `XMLInputFactory` -- creating those is very costly), or perhaps bottleneck is not in XML parsing and/or generation?

Answer (score 0):

I tried something similar in an attempt to parallelise.

anyway since I use the wikipedia data for many tasks, it was just simpler to generate a one-article-perline-dump which then I can run many experiments from in parallel.
It takes only a few minutes to run, then I have a dump which I can feed to Spark (in your case Storm) very easily.

If you want to use our tools check:
https://github.com/idio/wiki2vec

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do random access on XML document, but many Java XML parsers have somewhat more efficient skipping of unused content: Aalto and Woodstox for example defer decoding of String values (and construction of `String` objects) so that if tokens are skipped, no allocations are needed.

One thing to make sure with Stax is to NOT use `Event` API unless there is specific need to buffer contents -- it does not offer much functionality over basic Streaming API (`XMLStreamReader`), but does add significant allocation overhead since every `XMLEvent` is constructed, regardless of whether it is needed. Streaming API, on the other hand, only indicates type of Event/Token, and lets caller decide whether content (attributes, textual value) is needed and can avoid most of object allocations.